# How to read all records recursively and show by level depth TSQL

Tags: t-sql, select, recursion

Is there a way to read records recursively in similar table and order by depth level?

```
#table:

id int    |   parent int    |   value string
--------------------------------------------
1             -1                some
2             1                 some2
3             2                 some3
4             2                 some4
5             3                 some5
6             4                 some6
7             3                 some5
8             3                 some5
9             8                 some5
10            8                 some5
```

So is there a way to recursively select where result table would look like this.

```
select * from #table where id=3 

id int      | parent int      | value string   |  depth  
--------------------------------------------------------
3             2                 some3             0
5             3                 some5             1
7             3                 some5             1 
8             3                 some5             1
9             8                 some5             2
10            8                 some5             2
```

So if I choose id=3 I would see recursion for id=3 and children

Thank you

Comment: How are both tables related? Why have you skipped id 1?

Comment: It is same table, I just wanted to point what happens if I choose id=3 for select.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select id,
         parent,
         value,
         0 as depth
  from YourTable
  where id = 3
  union all
  select T.id,
         T.parent,
         T.value,
         C.depth + 1
  from YourTable as T
    inner join C  
      on T.parent = C.id
)
select *
from C
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67717)

Comment: Just as a pointer, this uses a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE). There is a lot written about them, so you can find a lot more information about them if you want to Google sql CTE.

Comment: Just a small addition - if YourTable have a lot of records then it would be a good idea in the second union all query to add a clause `Where C.Depth < 100`. Additionally I think max recursion level is 100, so if this is not enough for you, then at the very end just add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)` (this is the max possible level)

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish using CTEs, in particular rCTEs.

See [this](http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx&ei=laeXT_i6PJHV4QTuka3FBg&usg=AFQjCNE_EOC2EHMFw9nifV_MhE1VrIQUSg), and [this](http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx&ei=laeXT_i6PJHV4QTuka3FBg&usg=AFQjCNGqDsQG_x9V-0LaxOFwyUqMw-6zvg) for more information.

Example to follow:

```
WITH sampleCTE (id, parent, value, depth)
    AS (
        -- Anchor definition
        SELECT id
            , parent
            , value
            , 0
        FROM #table
        WHERE id = @targetId
        -- Recursive definition
        UNION ALL
        SELECT child.id
            , child.parent
            , child.value
            , sampleCTE.depth + 1
        FROM #table child 
            INNER JOIN sampleCTE ON sampleCTE.id = child.parent
    )
```