# How to use WITH table AS result within cursor loop to run stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, with-statement, database-cursor

How to get result in `WITH table AS` into `CURSOR` loop? I have previously asked about how to get recursive results from my table

[How to read all records recursively and show by level depth TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311080/how-to-read-all-records-recursively-and-show-by-level-depth-tsql)

```
;with C as
(
    definition ...
)
```

I have created CURSOR loop where I want to run specific stored procedure for all results in `table`

```
declare @id int, @parent int
declare cur cursor local fast_forward 
for 
    select id, parent from C
open cur
fetch next from cur into @id, @parent
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
    exec storedProcedure @id=@id, @parent=@parent
fetch next from cur into @id, @parent
end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Problem is that CURSOR doesnt know `table` from WITH AS result.

```
Invalid object name 'C'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temp table or a table variable to hold the rows returned by you CTE query and then you use that table as the source for your cursor.

```
declare @T table
(
  id int,
  parent int
)

;with C as
(
  select 1 as id, 2 as parent
)
insert into @T
select id, parent
from C

declare cur cursor for select id, parent from @T
```